# how can i update all my nuget dependencies at once using command line?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, dotnet-cli, .net-7.0

my projects has more than 400+ dependencies and I have to update all of them at once with command in .NET 7.0 .

I have try nukeeper,dotnet-outdated-tool and NuPu. nukeeper and dotnet- outdated is already deprecated and Nupu is used to update dependencies simultaneously(one by one). there are so many dependencies so I am not expecting GUI but with command only.

Comment: did you try dotnet CLI?

Comment: have you tried `dotnet tool update -g --no-cache` ?

Comment: yes i tried but its not working

Comment: @RahulDave please explain HOW it is not working. Cause it is hard to help you if we need to guess what is wrong.

Comment: @GuruStron I just tried nuget update on cmd but it is showing me this :- `No packages.config, project or solution file specified. Use the -self switch to update NuGet.exe` cause my project is in .net 7.0

Comment: Please try running `nuget update` or any other commands from the solution directory.

Comment: And actually it's risky to update all 400+ dependencies at once blindly.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @MikeMozhaev i tried that but its not working cause there is no package config file in .net 7.0

Comment: @GuruStron visual studio 2022

Answer (score 3):

> there are so many dependencies so I am not expecting GUI

If you are using Visual Studio or Rider you can bulk update nuget packages via UI.

**For VS**

Right click on the solution (or project), select "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...":

[image]

Then select "Updates" and click "Select all packages" and click "Update":

[image]

**For Rider**

Right click on the solution (or project), "Manage NuGet Packages":

[image]

Then in the NuGet management panel to the left click "Update packages in the Solution" icon:

[image]

And click "Upgrade":

[image]

For CLI you can try using 3rd party tool like [dotnet-outdated](https://github.com/dotnet-outdated/dotnet-outdated).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out a few different options. Sadly, no option really scales well with the number of projects and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think using dotnet CLI is:

```
dotnet list package
```

which (for example) would give:
[image]

Here you are able to see installed nugets, and now just execute

```
dotnet add package [package name]
```

which would fetch latest version (or you even can specify `--version` parameter if you want).

After running:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
```

I have latest version of nuget:
[image]